# An open source alternative to Wolfram Alpha

Tags: open-source, image-processing, math, scientific-computing, geography

I want an open source alternative to Wolfram Alpha that is like a QA system that:

- can take in natural language and process it
- have image processing functions
- has scientific functionality and geographic functionality just like Wolfram Alpha
- can do mathematical calculations (like a computer algebra system)

Some optional, but helpful requirements would be that:

- it uses machine learning
- it is based on Python
- uses a knowledgebase

The reason I want to find a Wolfram Alpha open source alternative is because I am interested in using a Wolfram Alpha-like system for one of my projects.

Edit:

I have found a program that is a demo for a Python module known as [quepy](http://quepy.machinalis.com). The program can take in natural language and search DBpedia.org or Freebase (two common knowledgebases) for results.

Something like this would satisfy my first requirement.

Comment: Maybe SageMath?  https://www.sagemath.org/

Answer (score 1):

Well, there isn't an open source tool that does everything you need. You will have to assemble the different parts together. Sympy, Sympy Gamma and Open Omnia are python based systems that do mathematical functions. 
SciKit Learn can help with the machine learning. It is also python based. It has a large amount of youtube tutorials.

Comment: (... please don't forget to [add disclosure](/help/promotion))

Comment: I am not able to find source code of Open Omnia, could you please share a link to e.g. Github?

Comment: I have found a source for Nerdamer (https://github.com/jiggzson/nerdamer), Open Omnia is based on this.